# Understanding why the answer is no?

Tags: probability, independence

Let $P (A) = 0.7$, $P(B^c) = 0.4$ and $P(B ~\text{and} ~C) = 0.48$

**a.** Find $P (A ~\text{or}~ B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are independent

$P(B) = 1 - P(B^c) = 1 - 0.4 = 0.6$

Seeing as $A$ and $B$ are independent $P(A ~\text{and}~ B) = 0.7 \times 0.6 = 0.42$

$P (A~\text{ or}~ B) = 0.7 + 0.6 - 0.42 = 0.88$

**b.** Is it possible that $A$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive if they are independent?

The answer in the book is no, they cannot be mutually exclusive, but I don't understand why? I thought events could be both mutually exclusive AND independent. Why is the answer no?

If anyone can explain why, (and double-check if my work for **a.** is right). I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and also use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: if it's mutually exclusive, it's the most dependent possible because the probability is 0 given one over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for the first part is correct.

If $A$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive and independent then $0=P(\emptyset)=P(A \cap C) =P(A)P(C)$ so either $P(A)=0$ or $P(C)=0$.